# Theano. Flatten all the parameters for later optimization

Tags: python, optimization, neural-network, theano

I opened the following issue with my problem:
https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/2920

Basically, I want to prepare all my model's parameters for future optimization. And I need to flatten and concatenate all my variables in order to find derivative later. But I am stuck.

If somebody knows how to solve it, please, share your wisdom :)

Comment: Without seeing more of your code it may not be possible to figure out either what you're trying to do or understand the error you've reported.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are usually Theano shared variables, not symbolic variables. The result of using `T.concatenate` is going to be a symbolic expression but I suspect you don't want that. Try just passing an ordinary Python list of parameters into `T.grad`.

So try,

```
self.theta = [self.hidden_layer.theta, self.log_layer.theta]
```

and

```
grad_theta = T.grad(cost_var, classifier.theta)
```